# Table formatting

Tags: tables, booktabs

I use the following table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline,    
        ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs} 


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]\hspace*{-1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcclll}
\toprule

Company& \multicolumn{2}{c}{exceedances (empirical)}&exeedances (expected)&no. of obs.\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}\\
&standard normal&standardized Student's-t&&\\
\midrule
Company1&1&5&9&13\\
Company2&2&6&10&14\\
Company3&3&11&15\\
Company4&4&8&12&16\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\begin{footnotesize}an additional hint about a detail\end{footnotesize}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here is the caption.}
\label{labelhere}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image: tableexample]

I have two problems:

1. The space after the `\cmidrule(r){2-3}` is too big, how can I change this?
2. The table looks not that good, how can I improve it in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some specific suggestions:

- group the table headers a bit more to emphasize the logical structure;
- break up the headers for columns 2 and 3 across two lines to make them less wide;
- don't use vertical whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the last column;
- use `\midrule[\heavyruleweight]` instead of `\bottomrule` to provide a bit more "breathing room for the next line.

Of course, these suggestions are personal and lay no claim to representing some greater truth...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcccc @{}} % suppress vertical whitespace at start and end
\toprule
Company& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Exceedances} & No.\ of Obs.\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Empirical} & Expected\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
&standard & standardized\\    % make columns 2 and 3 narrower
&normal   & Student's-$t$\\
\midrule
Company 1&1&5&9&13\\
Company 2&2&6&10&14\\
Company 3&3&11&15\\
Company 4&4&8&12&16\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth] % use "thick" \midrule instead of \bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize An additional hint about a detail}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here is the caption.}
\label{labelhere}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but I’d replace `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]` with `\bottomrule\addlinespace[\belowrulesep]` (both `booktabs` macros), which yields the same output, but is nicer semantically. I’m not sure if I like the `@{}`, but that’s a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to add a linebreak (`\\`) after `\cmidrule`. This fixes your first problem.

**Improvements**

- **align numbers.** You could correctly align numbers (at the decimal point which is not there) using the `siunitx`-package and the `S` column type (see below).
- **columns.** You have defined 6 columns but you only have five of them.

**Table with siunitx**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline,    
        ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs} 


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[H]\hspace*{-1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lSSSS}
\toprule
Company& \multicolumn{2}{c}{exceedances (empirical)}&{exeedances (expected)}&{no. of obs.}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
&{standard normal}&{standardized Student's-t}&\\
\midrule
Company1&1&5&9&13\\
Company2&2&6&10&14\\
Company3&3&11&15\\
Company4&4&8&12&16\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\begin{footnotesize}an additional hint about a detail\end{footnotesize}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Here is the caption.}
\label{labelhere}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I did not understand your first point: "You could correctly align numbers (at the decimal point which is not there)" What do you mean? I am not using a decimal seperator?

Comment: You see the result in the screenshot. The `9` is aligned to the `0` of `10`. Like this it is easier to compare the numbers.