# Table formatting, headings

Tags: tables

Do you know how can I set the following tables in LaTeX? (Just the first two lines are enough)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a MWE to start with?

Comment: You already accept one answer to your original question. If you now faced with new problem, than will be better to ask new question than edit old one. In it you can make link to this question and also clearly emphasize what is your new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `multicolumn` and `cline`.

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{well} & \tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
 &  & 1 & 2 & 3\tabularnewline
\hline 
some  & a & b & c & d\tabularnewline
\hline 
stuff & e & f & g & h\tabularnewline
\hline 
in & i & j & k & l\tabularnewline
\hline 
a & m & n & o & p\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really see the reason for using `\multirow` here.

Comment: you're right, I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Below existing links will help your request:

[Table formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110739/table-formatting)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=table+formatting

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code. But I changed the following lines and compiled.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lrcp{2.8cm}p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
&  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Proportions (\% )} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{ }\\
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{if not indicated otherwise}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{ OR (95\% Cl)for group differences}\\
\cmidrule{2-5}  
& Type 1 &  &  & \\ 
Outcome variable&diabetes &Control&Crude&Adjusted \tabularnewline
\midrule
```

I got the following

[image]

Comment: the text goes out of the table on the right